# Python Jupyter Notebook styled dataframe with borders

Tags: python, css, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using the following code to format the data frame with borders in jupyter

```
%%HTML
<style type="text/css">
table.dataframe td, table.dataframe th {
    border: 1px  black solid !important;
  color: black !important;
}
</style>

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame( data={'A': range(5), 'B':  np.arange(0, 1 , 0.2)})
```

[image]

but when I try to format the DataFrame I get the basic DataFrame,

```
df.style.format({
    'A': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'B': '{:,.2%}'.format,
})
```

[image]

So how can I change the code so the formated df will appear with the borders one?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Explaining the problem

When you set a style with `%%HTML`, you're targeting just those `HTML` elements that match your `CSS` selector.

When setting a `style` to a dataframe, and then displaying it in a cell, the `HTML Table` generated no longer has a `HTML Class` named `dataframe` (but a somewhat random ID). That's the reason your `%%HTML` didn't apply to the output of the styled dataframe.

What to do then?

### Possible solution

Setting the styles of the table itself through Pandas:

```
df.style.set_properties(
    **{'color': 'black !important',
       'border': '1px black solid !important'}
).set_table_styles([{
    'selector': 'th',
    'props': [('border', '1px black solid !important')]
}]).format({
    'A': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'B': '{:,.2%}'.format,
})
```

In these lines of code, you're both giving the dataframe an `HTML` style, and at the same time you're setting a formatting style to its columns.

**Important**: these two calls, for both `style.set_properties` and `style.format` must be chained. Otherwise, only the last one will be used.

### Solution: step by step

1.- So, given your initial commands:

[image: Initial commands]

2.- If you only apply styles on the columns:

[image: Styles on the columns]

3.- If you set properties for the cells:

[image: Properties for the cells]

4.- If you also set table properties, for example, on the `th` header elements:

[image: Also setting table properties, for th]

---

### To go further

If you want to share these styles among other DataFrames, then take a look at [Pandas Styling documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).

Comment: How can one apply different formats at different dataframe-tables? I 'd like to format for example one specific output with borders, how is this possible?